# PubNub: how to get last 5 messages

Tags: ios, pubnub

I have twenty-something messages in my Pubnub channel. Then I tried to get five last messages using

```
let startTimeToken = dateToTimeToken(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)) //unix time interval 0
let endTimeToken = dateToTimeToken(NSDate()) // now

self.pubnub?.historyForChannel(room, start: startTimeToken, end: endTimeToken,
        limit: 5, reverse: true, includeTimeToken: true, withCompletion: {
        (result, status) -> Void in
}
```

and discovered, that **whether reverse parameter is true or false, I always get FIRST five messages instead of last ones**.

And the only way to get last five messages is

```
self.pubnub?.historyForChannel(room, start: endTimeToken, end: nil,
        limit: 5, reverse: false, includeTimeToken: true, withCompletion: { 
        (result, status) -> Void in
}
```

but what on earth is that? 
start = end, end = nil, reverse = false
and you get last 5 messages?

I don't understand this logic first of all. And why the first statement ignore reverse parameter at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PubNub History Lesson ;)

The history API can be a bit cryptic at first but once you understand how it works, you can get exactly what you need. That said, we (PubNub) are working on a much enhanced, easier to use, more feature rich history API.

### Answers to your questions

1. When you provide a `start` and and `end` parameter, the `reverse` parameter is ignored and instead, the default is used, which is `false` which means get the messages starting from the newest timetoken (`end` parameter) and move backwards in time until 5 messages (your `count` parameter value) are retrieved.
2. If you just want the last 5 messages (the newest 5 messages), just set `start` and `end` to `nil`, set `count` to `5` and `reverse` to `false`. If you want the first 5 messages (the oldest 5 messages), then set `reverse` to `true`.

### Some basic rules of PubNub History

If you can learn the following rules of the `history` API, you will become an expert on this subject.

1. The maximum number of messages that can be returned per `history` call is 100. You can specify less than 100 using the `count` parameter, but you can not specify more. If you need more than 100 messages, you can page through history (not covering that here).
2. Using only a `start` parameter always returns messages *older* than the timetoken provided. If you set `reverse = true`, you will get message *newer* than the timetoken provided. And `start` is exclusive (a msg with timetoken = `start` is *NOT* returned).
3. Using only a `end` parameter always returns messages *newer* than the timetoken provided. If you set `reverse = true`, you will get message *older* than the timetoken provided. And `end` is inclusive (a msg with timetoken = `end` is returned).
4. When you provide a `start` and `end` parameter, the `reverse` parameter is ignored and the default, `false`, is used. This is because it will always just provide the results within that timetoken range.
5. The `reverse` parameter dictates which end of the timeline to search from: the oldest message and forwards (left to right), `reverse = true` or the newest message and backwards, `reverse = false` (the default).
6. If you call `history` with `reverse = false` and no other parameters (`start`, `end`, `count`), you will get *up to* the 100 newest messages (< 100 if there are fewer than 100 messages in history for that channel). This is because you are searching through history starting from the newest end of the timeline.
7. If you call `history` with `reverse = true` and no other parameters (`start`, `end`, `count`), you will get *up to* the 100 oldest messages (< 100 if there are fewer than 100 messages in history for that channel). This is because you are searching through history starting from the oldest end of the timeline.

See [Storage And Playback Getting Started Guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/getting-started-guides/pubnub-storage-and-playback) to learn more about how the PubNub `history` API works (with timeline diagrams).